# find uppercase letters and conver them into lower case vice versa using js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', createPassword)

function createPassword(){
    var len= document.getElementById('length').value;
    var password=''

    for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
        var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*94)+33
        password+= String.fromCharCode(random)
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerText=password;

    var uppercase= document.getElementById('uppercase')
    var upperCheck= uppercase.checked


    if(upperCheck!=true){

        var result=password.replace(/[A-Z]/g,/\U$1$2/);

        console.log(result)
    }



}
```

I'm trying to go through a string thats created randomly and convert all the upper case letters to lower case letters using regex and vice versa.

Comment: what's wrong with [String.prototype.toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)? What's wrong with not having the random include the capital letters in the first place? Does it have to be regex?

Comment: random string contains special characters, so that option wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as second argument of `replace` method to use `toLower/toUpperCase` functions with regex:

```js
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', createPassword)

function createPassword(){
    var len= document.getElementById('length').value;
    var password=''

    for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
        var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*94)+33
        password+= String.fromCharCode(random)
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerText="Generated: "+ password;

    var uppercase= document.getElementById('uppercase')

    var modified;
    console.clear(); // just to clear console if retried.
    if (uppercase.checked){
        modified = password.replace(/[a-z]/g,  function(match) {return match.toUpperCase(); });
    } else {
        modified = password.replace(/[A-Z]/g,  function(match) {return match.toLowerCase(); });
    }
    console.log("Modified:", modified)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="length" value ="10"/>

<input type="button" value="generate" id="generate"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="uppercase"/>
<p id="result"></p>
```